# How do I go about fitting a dataset in python? - lr.fit(x_train, y_train) giving me errors

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

Here is my code:

```
blood_df=pd.read_csv('blood_donation.csv')
x,y=blood_df.iloc[:,:-1], blood_df['Donated2020']
blood_df['Gender'].value_counts()
```

```
x_dummies = pd.get_dummies(x)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_dummies,y,random_state=0)
```

Then I start getting errors when I try to use the lr.fit below.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Here's a screengrab of the error because it's so hefty:
[error screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NyXj.png)

Comment: `Input contains NaN` Looks like `LinearRegression` doesn't like nan values. You need to impute those `NaN` values or drop them.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Answer (score 0):

Following Quang Hoang's advice in the comments, adding this worked:

```
#imputing missing values with their mean
blood_df=blood_df.fillna(blood_df.mean())
```